# How can I make widgets show properly in tinymce in magento 2.3?

Tags: wysiwyg, magento2.3.0, tinymce

I'm trying to add the tinymce wysiwyg editor in a custom field and make it look like in CMS pages however the widgets that I insert appear with an error image 
X
[image]
Any idea how to fix this issue?

I used the following code to retrieve the tinymce config settings

```
<?php 

 Class MyClass
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config
     */
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;

       .....
        $config = $this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig();
        $config = json_encode($config->getData());
?>
```

And in my js file I'm requiring `mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup`
and using the config data I created in my PHP class like this

```
        config.tinymce4.toolbar += " | code";

        var newAreaID = $newId;


        var editor = new wysiwygSetup(
            newAreaID,
            config
        );

        editorFormValidationHandler1 = editor.onFormValidation.bind(editor);

        varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler("formSubmit", editorFormValidationHandler1);
        varienGlobalEvents.clearEventHandlers("open_browser_callback");
        varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler("open_browser_callback", editor.openFileBrowser);

        console.log(editor);
        editor.wysiwygInstance.turnOn();
        jQuery('#' + newAreaID).addClass('wysiwyg-editor').data('wysiwygEditor', editor);
```

The widgets are completely usable and I can insert/delete/edit them but I have no clue which one is which because of how they're rendered.

I haven't been able to find something by searching. Any help is appreciated.